# PHP if value is null, send email

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I have a PHP script handling a form, but I want to send a specific confirmation email if the user has entered any info for a specific set of fields (`referral_1`, `referral_2`, etc.)

Right now I have this to check if the user entered any info in the referral fields (text inputs):

```
if($referral_1 or $referral_2 or $referral_3 or $referral_4 or $referral_5 == null) {
    $autosubject = stripslashes($autosubject);
    $automessage = stripslashes($automessage);
    mail($email,"$autosubject","$automessage","From: $recipientname <$recipientemail>");
}

if($referral_1 or $referral_2 or $referral_3 or $referral_4 or $referral_5 != null) {
    $autosubject = stripslashes($autosubject);
    $automessage = stripslashes($automessage);
    mail($email,"$autosubject2","$automessage2","From: $recipientname <$recipientemail>");
}
```

But it's sending both emails when the user completes the referral fields. When they do not enter any referral info, it seems to work just fine (they only get the specified confirmation email). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those variables are coming directly from $_POST, then they'll never be null, e.g. a url like

```
http://example.com/script.php?field=
```

will produce

```
$_GET['field'] = '';
```

and contain an empty string, not a null value.

Beyond that, your logic is faulty, it's being parsed as:

```
if (($referral_1 != '') or ($referral_2 != '') etc...)
```

For your statement to work, you need to bracket the `or` bits, because `or` has a LOWER precedence than `==`, so...

```
if (($referral_1 or .... or $referal_5) == null) {
    ^---                              ^--- new brackets
```

Which opens another can of worms. The `or` sequence will produce a boolean true or false, never a `null`. so, what you really want is simply:

```
if ($referral_1 or ... $referal_5) {
   ... a referal was specified in at least ONE of those fields.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP boolean comparisons don't work this way.  You cannot chain them with a comparison to the first or last argument.  Instead you need something like:

```
// Build an array of all the values and test NULL appears in the array
if(in_array(NULL, array($referral_1, $referral_2, $referral_3, $referral_4, $referral_5)) {

// ADDED:
// To test if any value is NOT NULL, you can't use in_array(). Instead you can use
// array_filter() and check if the output array has any values
// This is complicated, and unless there are a lot of values to check, I'd probably just write
// out all each one longhand...
if (count(array_filter(array($referral_1, $referral_2, $referral_3, $referral_4, $referral_5), function($v) {return !is_null($v);})) > 0) {
   // There's a non-null
}
```

**Note** To use an anonymous function in `array_filter()` like this requires PHP 5.3.

Or write them out longhand with a full comparison for each:

```
if($referral_1 === NULL or $referral_2 === NULL or $referral_3 === NULL or $referral_4 === NULL or $referral_5 === null) {
```

Doing it the way you did, PHP's short circuit evaluation takes over, and the first *non-null* value in the list returns TRUE, making the whole thing TRUE.

Comment: Thanks. How would I make comparison to check for the opposite? `if(in_array(isset, array(...`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check each referrer variable individually to see if they are null:

```
if(is_null($referral_1) || is_null($referral_2) || is_null($referral_3) || is_null($referral_4) || is_null($referral_5)) {
```

I also recommend using [`is_null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) instead of `== null`

Comment: Thanks. Why is `is_null` better?

Comment: It's more readable and allows you to count on PHP doing all of the right things behind the scenes to make sure the value really is null. That may or may not go beyond a simple comparison but that's up for PHP to worry about, not us.

Answer (score 1):

I would exploit the fact that isset() returns false if the value is null, and that it can check multiple values:

```
if (isset($referral_1, $referral_2, $referral_3, $referral_4, $referral_5)) {
 // all values are not-null
} else {
 // at least one value is not null
}
```

if you want to check if all values are null:

```
if (is_null($referral_1) and is_null($referral_2) and is_null($referral_3) and is_null($referral_4) and is_null($referral_5)) {
// all values are null
}
```

Comment: This might be what I'm after. As long as the user fills out one of the fields, I want to send them email 1, if they fill out none, they get email 2.